# Python cant strip text from API response

Tags: python, discord.py

The code is in `discord.py`

```py
@client.command()
async def portscan(ctx, ip):
    url = ("https://api.hackertarget.com/nmap/?q=" + ip)
    r = requests.get(url)
    ports = r.text.strip(' ( https://nmap.org/ )')
    embed=discord.Embed(description=f"{ports}", color=16738740)  
    embed.set_author(name="Nmap Results For " + ip)   
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

however the output is just the `API` response without stripping the text

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what `.strip(...)` does. Try `'aaabbbcccdefg'.strip('cba')` in an interactive prompt. In addition, it is always best to post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem might be with the fact that `strip` cleans the text from the beginning and the end of the text (`'asada'.strip('a') == 'sad'`).

This is the response you get for a random IP:

```
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-21 16:35 UTC
Nmap scan report for 215.13.23.23
Host is up.

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp   filtered ftp
22/tcp   filtered ssh
23/tcp   filtered telnet
80/tcp   filtered http
110/tcp  filtered pop3
143/tcp  filtered imap
443/tcp  filtered https
3389/tcp filtered ms-wbt-server

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.27 seconds
```

Since you are trying to `.strip(' ( https://nmap.org/ )')` it won't do any thing.

if you want you can call (`.replace(' ( https://nmap.org/ )', '')`, to remove it from the middle of the text.